# copy an operator to another object

Tags: modeling, python

I want to synchronize the operation on one object to another object that is similar but not identical. For example, moving a vertex, after clicking a button, the vertex of the corresponding position (same or centrosymmetric) of another object will also move the same distance.How can I achieve this ? Or have other ideas?[image]

Comment: you have to explain much more detailed, how that vertex in what case should move where. Else the answer is just: yes, that's possible, but we have no idea how exactly you want that. It is possible e.g. via animation nodes, geometry nodes, python

Comment: @Chris with python to achieve this, such as the operators in suclpt mode.